# How to mask the sensitive information contained in a file using tcl?

Tags: tcl, password-encryption

I'm trying to implement a tcl script which reads a text file, and masks all the sensitive information (such as passwords, ip addresses etc) contained it and writes the output to another file.

As of now I'm just substituting this data with **** or ##### and searching the entire file with regexp to find the stuff which I need to mask. But since my text file can be 100K lines of text or more, this is turning out to be incredibly inefficient.

Are there any built in tcl functions/commands I can make use of to do this faster? Do any of the add on packages provide extra options which can help get this done?

Note: I'm using tcl 8.4 (But if there are ways to do this in newer versions of tcl, please do point me to them)

Comment: Can you post your regular expressions? `string match` or `string first` together with `string replace` may be faster. You'll have to test it and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should put your code in a procedure to get best performance out of Tcl. (You have got a few more related options in 8.5 and 8.6, such as lambda terms and class methods, but they're closely related to procedures.) You should also be careful with a number of other things:

- Put your expressions in braces (`expr {$a + $b}` instead of `expr $a + $b`) as that enables a much more efficient compilation strategy.
- Pick your channel encodings carefully. (If you do `fconfigure $chan -translation binary`, that channel will transfer *bytes* and not *characters*. However, `gets` is not be very efficient on byte-oriented channels in 8.4. Using `-encoding iso8859-1 -translation lf` will give most of the benefits there.)
- Tcl does channel buffering quite well.
- It might be worth benchmarking your code with different versions of Tcl to see which works best. Try using a [*tclkit* build](http://www.patthoyts.tk/tclkit/) for testing if you don't want to go to the (minor) hassle of having multiple Tcl interpreters installed just for testing.

The idiomatic way to do line-oriented transformations would be:

```
proc transformFile {sourceFile targetFile RE replacement} {
    # Open for reading
    set fin [open $sourceFile]
    fconfigure $fin -encoding iso8859-1 -translation lf

    # Open for writing
    set fout [open $targetFile w]
    fconfigure $fout -encoding iso8859-1 -translation lf

    # Iterate over the lines, applying the replacement
    while {[gets $fin line] >= 0} {
        regsub -- $RE $line $replacement line
        puts $fout $line
    }

    # All done
    close $fin
    close $fout
}
```

If the file is small enough that it can all fit in memory easily, this is more efficient because the entire match-replace loop is hoisted into the C level:

```
proc transformFile {sourceFile targetFile RE replacement} {
    # Open for reading
    set fin [open $sourceFile]
    fconfigure $fin -encoding iso8859-1 -translation lf

    # Open for writing
    set fout [open $targetFile w]
    fconfigure $fout -encoding iso8859-1 -translation lf

    # Apply the replacement over all lines
    regsub -all -line -- $RE [read $fin] $replacement outputlines
    puts $fout $outputlines

    # All done
    close $fin
    close $fout
}
```

Finally, regular expressions aren't necessarily the fastest way to do matching of strings (for example, `string match` is much faster, but accepts a far more restricted type of pattern). Transforming one style of replacement code to another and getting it to go really fast is not 100% trivial (REs are really flexible).

Answer (score 1):

A file with 100K lines is not that much (unless every line is 1K chars long :) so I'd suggest you `read` the entire file into a var and make the substitution on that var:

```
set fd [open file r+]
set buf [read $fd]
set buf [regsub -all $(the-passwd-pattern) $buf ****]
# write it back
seek $fd 0; # This is not safe! See potrzebie's comment for details.
puts -nonewline $fd $buf
close $fd
```

Comment: If more characters are removed than added, you'll end up with some of the old contents after the end of the new contents. Use `chan truncate` (Tcl 8.5) before closing the stream or open two different files.

Comment: Even a file with a million characters isn't really that much when you've got gigabytes of memory…

Answer (score 1):

Especially for very large files - as mentioned - it's not the best way to read the whole file into a variable. As soon as your system runs out of memory you can't prevent your app crashes. For data that is separated by line breaks, the easiest solution is to buffer one line and process it.

Just to give you an example:

```
# Open old and new file
set old [open "input.txt" r]
set new [open "output.txt" w]
# Configure input channel to provide data separated by line breaks
fconfigure $old -buffering line
# Until the end of the file is reached:
while {[gets $old ln] != -1} {
    # Mask sensitive information on variable ln
    ...
    # Write back line to new file
    puts $new $ln
}
# Close channels
close $old
close $new
```

I can't think of any better way to process large files in Tcl - please feel free to tell me any better solution. But Tcl was not made to process large data files. For real performance you may use a compiled instead of a scripted programming language.

**Edit:** Replaced `![eof $old]` in while loop.

Comment: Not tested but I believe some scripting languages (like `Perl`) should perform very well for this kind of work. :)

Comment: I never used `Perl` so far, but I can tell that compiled programs always have more performance compared with scripted programs - that's axiomatic.

Comment: Don't use `eof` as your while-condition (http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html#eof) -- the TCL  idiom to read a file line-by-line is: `while {[gets $old line] != -1} {...`

Comment: Corrected my example code as suggested - thanks to @glennjackman

Comment: Tcl does pretty well at processing large files provided you set the channel encoding right and use other general performance-boosting techniques like putting your processing in a procedure. (Also, _measure the performance_ with different versions of Tcl; it's not constant across all versions, but whether things speed up or not is dependent on the detail of what is being done.)